# How do I replace Pattern.DOTALL by using a String.replaceAll function?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am creating simple project that is a simple IDE.

I am detecting comments of a source code (Long String) inside the IDE and removing it.

I have tried many regular expressions to detect comments and this regex has worked most consistently for me to detect comments:

```
Pattern commentsSingle = Pattern.compile("\\/\\/.*");
Pattern commentsMulti = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

I would like to modify this comments detection to be able to remove comments using a `String.replaceAll` method.

I can easily do it for single line comments by:

```
code = code.replaceAll("\\/\\/.*", "");
```

However, the multi line comments has a `Pattern.DOTALL`, hence I could not use the String.replceAll methods properly.

Can anyone help to modify the regex or call an alternate method so I can replace multi line comments properly?

Some regex I have tried:

```
("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)",""))
```

**The above regex causes stackoverflow exception sometimes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `String.replaceAll`, you can use [`replaceAll(String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) from [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), then you can construct a pattern using `Pattern.DOTALL`:

Looks something like this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(comment);
final String strWithoutComments = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

An example will look like this:

```
final String code = "/**\n" + 
                    " * \n" + 
                    " * @param args\n" + 
                    " */\n" +
                    "public static void main(final String[] args) { }\n";
final String codeWithoutComments = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(code)
        .replaceAll("");
System.out.println(code);
System.out.println(codeWithoutComments);
```

Will print this before replace:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) { }
```

And this, after replace:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) { }
```